# PL/SQL Query efficiency improvement

Tags: c#, sql, plsql

Hi guys I hope you can help me with a SQL query I'm trying to write. I have achieved the table I want but I have to build it up row by row. This is not efficient and when I end up with 200 rows this is slowing the website down.

This is what my Table looks like:

```
FeedBack Table: 

RatingID |  RATING| TUTORIAL_ID|    TUTORIAL_NAME

5716|   4  |    993|    Test002

5717|   3  |    993|    Test002

5777|   1  |    994|    eClip3

5886|   1  |    994|    eClip3

7127|   4  |    1235|   FTIR001

7128|   4  |    1235|   FTIR001

7169|   3  |    1235|   FTIR001

7170|   2  |    1235|   FTIR001

7131|   4  |    1235|   FTIR001

7187|   3  |    1235|   FTIR001

7132|   3  |    1235|   FTIR001
```

What I wanted to produce was a table of all the unique tutorial names and then the Total number of times that specific tutorial was rated;

```
1(not useful), 2(somewhat useful), 3(useful), 4(Very Useful)
```

So The query should make:

```
Tutorial Name | not Useful | Somewhat Useful| Useful| Very Useful

Test002| 0| 0|1|1

eClip3|2|0|0|0

FTIR001| 0| 1| 3| 3
```

The table is being shown on a webpage with C# behind. Currently I loop through the table to find a list of individual tutorial names then for each clip name I select Count(*) where rating = 1 etc.. and build the table up row by row.

What I really want to know is if there is a way to do all of this at once. This would imporve the efficiency of the website greatly as there are 200+ tutorials I want to show data for.

Comment: Look into plsql grouping http://psoug.org/definition/GROUPING.htm or perhaps even better linq grouping http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select tutorial_name, 
       sum(case when rating=1 then 1 else 0 end) "not Useful",
       sum(case when rating=2 then 1 else 0 end) "Somewhat Useful",
       sum(case when rating=3 then 1 else 0 end) "Useful",
       sum(case when rating=4 then 1 else 0 end) "Very Useful"
  from feedback
  group by tutorial_name;
```

is the query you need.